# How to learn BEAM robotics?

Tags: robotics

### Old Topic:

Can I make robot only circuit without microcontroller?

What knowledge should I know, where can I get it?

### UPDATE:

How to learn [BEAM robotics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEAM_robotics)

Answer (score 2):

I really liked "[JunkBots, Bugbots, and Bots on Wheels: Building Simple Robots With BEAM Technology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072226013)". It does a really good job of introducing the BEAM aesthetics, such as they are.

However, if you really need to start from the beginning, [Robot Building for Beginners (Technology in Action)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430227486) might be the best place to start. It's very thorough, and gives what is probably the best advice I've ever read: "Stop being a visionary and start building something." There's no substitute for experimentation!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you start by asking yourself, "what do I want my robot to do" and coming up with methods to accomplish the tasks? Then, find the components which have microcontrollers in them, and try to figure out if the microcontroller is a crucial aspect of its function.

For example, many servos and motors interface through a 3-pin servo connector which interprets a PPM (pulse position modulation) signal on the white wire. A microcontroller is particularly suitable for generating a signal such as this. Now you see why you could benefit greatly from learning how these technologies work.

Comment: Maybe my question misleading, I want to know more about the circuit can do in automation

Comment: your question is not so much misleading as *vague*. Depending on the nature of what is automated, a microcontroller is quite often the best option.

Answer (score -1):

A quick google [search](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=BEAM+robotics) will yield lots of information - including a [wiki](http://www.beam-wiki.org/wiki/Main_Page), which happens to have lots of information about BEAM robotics. Next, pick up some electronic components and start hacking away!

Good luck!